# jQuery - Owl Carousel - How to place an element in an owl item that doesn't let it swipe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe, jgestures

I'm making a Javascript application that uses [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/).
In one item i've placed a div that listenes to [jgestures](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/documentation) gestures.
The gestures I am listening to are swipe gestures. But when I swipe on the div, also the Owl Carousel swipes to the next/previous item.

this is my code of the jgesture

```
function(event_, obj) {
    // ignore bubbled handlers
    // if ( obj.originalEvent.currentTarget !== obj.originalEvent.target ) {
    // return; }
    obj.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    obj.originalEvent.stopPropagation(); //Should stop it from swiping?
}
```

The carousel still swipes..
What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ..
 preventParentSwipe:function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
 }
 ..
 $("#swipe").on('touchstart.owl mousedown.owl',preventParentSwipe);
```

swipe is the container where you bind the jgestures on.